# С++ поиск самодостаточной библиотеки для работы с видео

Tags: c++, видео, поиск-библиотек

Доброго времени суток! Ищу легковесную самодостаточную библиотеку для работы с видео на C++ под следующие задачи:
преобразование avi файла в набор изображений (bmp,jpg,png) покадраво;
Создание видео из картинок с заданием частоты кадров;

Какие есть варианты? Также приветствуются готовые решения для создания таймлапс и извлечения кадра так как **основная задача сделать таймлапс из 18 часовой записи с регистратора, а также возможность извлеч кадр в картинку**.

Comment: fmpeg https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

Comment: opencv лучше всего